# Is there a way to ensure a class library uses it's own app settings?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, c#-4.0

I have a class library at the moment and it's going to need its own appsettings and it's likely going to need to change them and stuff.

The only problem is that the class is going to be called by a web application which has an appsettings file that also has identical keys to the class library app settings.

I would like to ensure that the class library uses it's own appsettings file and also that it doesn't make changes to the web application's appsettings.

Is this possible? It seems like any assembly can change the appsettings via ConfigurationManager.

EDIT - To give context, the class library accesses a data tier assembly (which I can't change) which uses a value in the appSettings to get the connection string. Only problem is that key is the same as the web app's connection string (which may or may not have a different value).

I don't want the class library to change the appSetting value for that key, and then have the web app start accessing a different database.

Answer (score 1):

A separate app domain can use a different config file, I believe.  I'm not sure how else you could do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is *no* way to do this. It simply isn't how .NET works.

Consider that the class library could be used in two separate applications. Each application might need different settings for the same class library. The only way this works is if one does *not* use the config file from the class library.

Comment: Not the *only* way. Put apps in separate folders, give each copy of the library it's own config. This certainly would work, would not it? (That is if .net supported this, which it does not)

Comment: I wouldn't sat that there's _no way_. It's more like there's no built-in way.

Comment: @zespri: the way to do it is put apps in different folders, then set the app.config or web.config appropriately. Put the settings used by the library into the .config file used by the application.

Comment: I know, I know. I'm just commenting that the statement that you've made with "The only way this works" in it is not entirely correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the app/web.config file consider building your own settings class that inherits from System.Configuration.SettingsBase.

Your class library can then instantiate a copy of this SettingsBase implementation  and manage its own settings without interferes with settings that might be required elsewhere.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsbase.aspx

The settings class would look something like this:

```
sealed class MySettings : SettingsBase
{
    [ApplicationScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue("Default")]
    public string MySetting
    {
        get { return this["MySetting"].ToString(); }
        set { this["MySetting"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a sensible idea. Unfortunately, the data tier which my class library calls gets the connection string from the appsettings. It's an auto-gen solution, not much I can do to change that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx) to get the configuration for a specific file from within your class library.

```
 // Map the new configuration file.
 var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
 configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;

 // Get the mapped configuration file
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Here config will give you access to AppSettings, ConnectionStrings and Sections. You *could* create an abstraction on top of the access to the ConfigurationManager so you can control its access and thus make it more testable but that depends on the design.

As you mentioned auto generated code in one of your answers there are sometimes ways around that. Most likely that class is marked as partial which you might be able to initialize with the correct 'Configuration' object and therefor the correct connection string

Answer (score 1):

Name your config file like below and place it in the same folder as your assembly:
[AssemblyName].dll.config

**Update:** Anything that goes under  can be used. You also use AppSettingsReader (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingsreader.aspx) to create custom settings.

ex:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="YourCustomSetting" value="10240" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    ...
  </system.diagnostics>

  <connectionStrings>...
  <system.web>...
  etc, etc.
</configuration>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. What kind of settings can you change from here? Is it only appSettings or do you use it for more?

Comment: Just search your C:\ for "*.dll.config" you'll see many examples of it being used.

Comment: @stickman Try to read a custom setting using the AppSettingsReader as mentioned above and see if that works.